# Can I share a service between Angular and Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a standard utility service in my Angular5 Typescript app.
I want to share that with my node application, which is serving the app.

I can't find any info around it but I see issues as:

- Using require() to import a TS file, and if the generated js file
  lives in the same place
- Ignoring the @Injectable which is a decorator
  used on the angular service.

I assume it's possible as that's a major benefit of using full stack Javascript, but how can it be done?

I've  tried the following in NodeJs, which throws an error:

```
const utilService = require('../../src/app/services/util/util.service');
```

Comment: I feel like the answer lies in writting the 'guts' of the code for the service in JS.  Then create a serive in TS which simply wraps or creates a bridge to the JS code.  Then you can import the JS code directly in node.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern

Comment: Found anything? Actually I'm interested to know

Comment: i think the best option would be to create a private npm module that both inherit

Answer (score 2):

I would create a [private npm package](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) containing your utilities requests.

Then import it into your angular project and node project.

Comment: It's actually a good idea - I only wanted to use one method so will see if there's another solution, otherwise will mark as correct

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of how you can achieve this, is to provide a compiled (ES2015 and below) representation of your util.service. doing this could be an automated part of your build script/pipeline.

Or, if the util.service does not change that often, compile it by hand with

```
tsc ./src/app/services/util/util.service.ts --out ./src/app/services/util/util.service.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, typescript it's not valid javascript.

For that to work you would also have to compile your node code, basically having two different typescript configs, one targeting browsers, and another one with a different entry point, targeting node.

If you do that, then you will be able to share some code between your backend and front end. Although services that use the @injectable() decorator, won't work. Why? there isn't any Injector available to handle your dependency injections.